# Angular Using Promises and Async Functions

Tags: angular, async-await, promise

I am trying to retrieve data from one http request. After this operation I populate my variable with the response.
I use that variable in a second function to populate my form.  All I need is second function must wait for the first function to finish its cycle.
What am I doing wrong here?

---

Here is my code below:

> spec-component.ts

```
  async init() {
    await this.getBaseSpecs();
    await this.matchOfferingModelSpecifications(this.baseSpecList, this.offeringModel);
  }


      getBaseSpecs() {
    this.specificationService.getAllSpecifications('offeringBase').toPromise().then((specificationList) => {
      if (specificationList && specificationList.length > 0) {
        this.baseSpecList = specificationList[0].parameters;
      }
    });
  }

  matchOfferingModelSpecifications(parameterList: ParameterModel[], offeringModel: OfferingModel) {
    const resultParameterList: ParameterModel[] = [];
    for (const offeringParameter of offeringModel.specifications[0].parameters) {
      for (const defaultParameter of parameterList) {

        if (offeringParameter.name === defaultParameter.name) {
          resultParameterList.push(offeringParameter);
        }
        this.modalForm.addControl(offeringParameter.name, new FormControl(offeringParameter.value.toString()));

      }
    }

    offeringModel.specifications[0].parameters = resultParameterList;
  }
```

> spec-service.ts

```
  getAllSpecifications(specName: string) {
    return this.http.get<SpecificationModel[]>(`${environment.api_url}/specification?specName=${specName}`);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

All your trying is correct.

```
async doAll() {
  try {
    const res = await this.service.getAllSpecifications(name).toPromise();
    const basicList =  res[0].parameters;
    // do your second function.
  } catch (e) {
  } finally {
  }
}

// and call this function from ngOnInit()
```

Maybe this is much more human readable code...